# DataTable : How to make a certain column bold and center ?

Tags: css, datatables

I used DataTable, and I want to make a certain column bold and place it in the center. How do I do that ?

Here is my setting now :

```
  // Setting to Inventory Table 
  $('#inventory_exact').dataTable({

    "lengthMenu": [ 10 ] ,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "searchHighlight": true,
    "bInfo" : false,
    "bRegex" : false,
    "bSmart" : false,
    "sSearch" :"^\\s*"+'1'+"\\s*$"


  });
```

Here is what it look like right now :

[image]

Comment: What is your HTML output from this? Can you set up a jsfiddle for us to see?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why cant you use simple CSS? Lets say you want to have the third column in bold and the text aligned to center :

```css
#inventory_exact td:nth-child(3),
#inventory_exact th:nth-child(3) {
    text-align : center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

jQuery dataTables 1.10.x demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/1s1kfzja/**

Comment: how can i use this in jquery?

Comment: @IamnotBatman, straight forward, there is no hocus pocus about jQuery, it uses CSS selectors as well (in fact, the heart of jQuery is nothing but a CSS selector parser) -> `$('#inventory_exact td:nth-child(3)').css('font-weight', 'bold');` etc.

Comment: this is not working for me.. I load data to datatables using ajax. Does it matter?

Comment: @IamnotBatman, yes - the jQuery works on specific live elements,  the CSS will work always on any element. But I dont know your setup, what you are doing in details, so cannot say for sure what you need to do.